# What is the purpose of "::" in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, special-characters

In (non-English) book on T-SQL (SQL Server 2005) I read about:

```
SELECT * FROM ::fn_helpcollations()
```

Though, execution of it without "`::`"

```
SELECT * FROM fn_helpcollations()
```

In my SQL Server 2008 R2 gives exactly the same result.

What does "`::`" mean in T-SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175085(v=sql.80).aspx):

> However, when you call SQL Server
> built-in functions that return a
> table, you must add the prefix :: to
> the name of the function:
>
> `SELECT * FROM ::fn_helpcollations()`

Looks like you can omit the `::` in SQL Server 2005 and 2008. The `::` syntax will be supported for backward compatibility.